# I overstayed in the US by about 4 years in 1997 and left voluntarily. Can I now come back as a tourist?

Tags: visas, usa, overstaying

I overstayed my visitors visa by just over 4 years, but returned home in 1997 - will I still be able to gain access to the USA when going on a holiday after all this time?  I was never deported and never stopped at the airport - I just left the USA as a normal traveller.  The ESTA form asks if you have ever overstayed - do I put yes or no?

I was a single woman when I came home, but am now married (separated) with two children under 18.  I have my own business in the UK and would have no intention of staying in the USA except on a family holiday.   What would be the consequences if I answered 'no' on the application form?

Comment: Never lie on your application form. That's the best way to be refused entry. For a long time.

Answer (score 9):

As JoErNanO's comment says, don't ever lie to visa or immigration officials.

As you have overstayed in the past, you will probably not be eligible to use VWP, and will thus have to apply for a visa instead.